# Доброго времени суток, уважаемые девелЯ начинающий в it сфере! хотел бы задать вопросы опытным программистом!

Tags: android, любой-язык, vr, умный-дом

1) на чем пишут vr разработку? это может быть как мобильные приложений под андроид(смартфоны,часы и так далее) так и игры
2) на каком языке лучше писать исскуственный интелект и умные дома?
3) на каком языке программируют беспилотные машины,поезда, самолеты и так далее
4) и наконец какие языки в будущем будут актуальны и профессии?

можно пожалуйста по подробнее! всем спасибо

Comment: умный дом можно Arduino сделать.  по идее и теслу собрать можно и беспилотник. 4й вопрос не поддаётся вычислению в долгосрочной перспективе , только гадание. vr слишком требовательный, лучше на дополненую реальность обратить взор. @имхо